# Ionic 2 - Local image wont display

Tags: javascript, html, image, ionic2, local

im pretty new to Ionic 2. I switched from Ionic 1 because it feels to be the better choice. To me it seems like a lot of structural and syntax changes have been made.

Currently im trying to use a local picture in one page. Thatswhy i tried to use this code.

```html
<img src="../../../www/img/icon.jpeg">
```

Unfortunately it doesn´t work. Thatswhy i began to google it, they recommended to make some changes in the gulpfile js. Does this still exist? It seems like they also changed alot between the beta- and the release version.

Thanks alot in advance.

Greetings,
Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the current version of Ionic (RC1) including all the surroundings like app-scripts you are supposed to put your images to src/assets.
During the build process ('ionic serve' or 'ionic build [PLATFORM]') this will be copied over to www/assets.
In order to link them properly in your templates you have to link them like this:

```
<img src="assets/icon.jpeg">
```

I personally created an img folder within the assets folder to separate it from other content. Obviously in that case you have to adjust the link to something like

```
<img src="assets/img/icon.jpeg">
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop `ionic serve` by using `Ctrl+C`.
2. Open `package.json`.
3. Remove `homepage` field.
4. Start `ionic serve` using `ionic serve` command.

It should work. In my case it was looking for `assets` folder at url mentioned as `homepage` instead of looking into local folders.